# Simple CSS centering (centering text + tall image inside a div)

Tags: html, css, xhtml, css-float

I have been trying to do the following. I have a `<div>` element
which spans the whole width of its parent div. Inside of this
I would like to place A. some text and B. an image.

A. some text (either loose text or text enclosed in a `<p>`, `<h2>`,
   or `<span>`, or `<div>` element), on the left.

B. an image defined via an `<img>` element whose both height and width
   are known.

Other requirements:

1. There must be 12px of space between the text and the `<img>` element.
2. Important: both the text from A. and the image from B. must be
   centered as a group.
3. The text from A. must be vertically centered in its enclosing space.

How can I achieve this effect? I have tried different things but cannot
manage to place the image to the right of the text and cannot manage to
have the text A. vertically centered.

Anyone know how to solve this simple problem?

---

Thank you all for your answers, seems CSS makes simple things so hard,
anyways:

```
  div#content_whatsnew, div#content_bestsellers { clear: both; height: 108px; font-size: xx-large; text-transform: uppercase; margin-left: 380px; }
  div#content_whatsnew p, div#content_bestsellers p { float: left; height: 108px; line-height: 108px; padding: 8px 12px 0px 0px; color: black; }
  div#content_whatsnew img, div#content_bestsellers img { float: left; height: 108px; }
```

Comment: Could you draw us a diagram or attach an image of what you are trying to accomplish, also could you let us know what you have already tried.

Comment: Vertical centering: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve? http://dabblet.com/gist/3130292

Comment: This is not so good. Look at what happens when the browser window is shrinked.

Comment: What behavior are you looking for on small windows?

Comment: Same question: how should it behave on resize?

Comment: I've updated the demo to make it behave better on small screens.

Comment: OK, that's much better, at least the text and the image stay on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<div class="my-outer-container">
 <div class="my-inner-container">
  <div class="my-text">Here is my text, it is lovely text.</div>
  <img src="my-image.jpg" alt="" class="my-image" />
 </div>
</div>

.my-outer-container {
 width:auto;
 text-align:center;
}

.my-inner-container {
 width:XXXpx; /* enter whatever the width you want here is */
 margin:0 auto;
 overflow:auto;
}

.my-text {
 width:XXXpx; /* enter whatever the width you want here is */
 float:left;
 margin-right:12px;
}

.my-image {
 width:XXXpx; /* enter whatever the width you want here is */
 height:XXXpx; /* enter whatever the height you want here is */
 float:left;
}
```

Then maybe use the vertical centering tip on the link provided above by @biziclop

Comment: Remember to float your containers left (;

Comment: @Oliver - Not sure what you'd float the containers unless I'm missing a trick? I'm already floating the text div and the image.

Answer (score 1):

Is this about right?

http://jsfiddle.net/89twb/2/

For aligning text, [check this out](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp).

And for placing elements next to each other, [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp).

Answer (score 1):

In order to center a div, it has to have a fixed width. If it spans the width of its parent div, you can only then center things inside it. So it sounds to me like the best solution would be to place your text in a fixed-width left-floated div, and do the same for your image, and then place those both in a fixed-width holder div, which is centered with margin:auto;

Here's an example: http://dabblet.com/gist/3130148

Edit- I vertically centered the text by placing it in a table. Tables are the only surefire way to vertically center something cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

The most intuitive way would be using 'vertical-align:middle;' but it often tends not the way you want it to work.

I did some research and found this code from here. http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Hope this helps!

```
<style type="text/css">
    #myoutercontainer { position:relative }
    #myinnercontainer { position:absolute; top:50%; height:10em; margin-top:-5em }
</style>

<div id="myoutercontainer">
    <div id="myinnercontainer">
        <p>Hey look! I'm vertically centered!</p>
        <p>How sweet is this?!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```